# python3で深さ優先探索の再帰関数が上手く機能しない

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

こんにちは。python3で作ったこちらの再帰関数が上手く機能しません。

```
    def func(teleports_string):
        strings = [{n[0],n[1]} for n in teleports_string.split(',')]
        start = {'1'}

        def search(strings,point,totalpoint):
            for string in strings:

                if point <= string and not string.difference(point) <= totalpoint:

                    if len(totalpoint.union(point)) >= 7:

                        print(totalpoint)
                        return totalpoint

                    search(strings,string.difference(point),totalpoint.union(string))
        return search(strings,start,set())

func("12,23,34,45,56,67,78,81")
```

上記のコードの
`return totalpoint`
の行で`totalpoint`を戻り値として処理を終了させたいのですが、
残りの処理を始めてしまいます。
どのようにすれば、`return totalpoint`で処理を終わらせられるでしょうか。
ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 1):

`search` 関数の最後で自分自身を再帰的に呼び出していますが、

```
search(strings,string.difference(point),totalpoint.union(string))
```

ここに `return` がないので、再帰から戻ってきた後も、外側の `for string in strings:` を続けて実行しています。しかも、最終的には return なしで関数が終了しているので、何も戻り値を返していません(厳密には `None` を返していますが)。